# MySQL Query ; Finding if two person sharing the same group

Tags: mysql

Let's say on the MySQL Table, userid=A and userid=B.

userid=A belongs to Group1, Group5, Group6, Group8

userid=B belongs to Group2, Group9, Group5, Group10.

What's MYSQL query statement of finding the two users's common group which is Group5 in this case.

The intersection query

Comment: You do mean Group5, right? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from group_table where group_id = id AND (userid = a or userid = b)
```

if the count is 2 then they're both members of the group.